# Changed bios setting then computer startup failed

Tags: memory, motherboard, bios

I have a custom computer running windows 10 with a 8g of ram, an asus M5A99x motherboard with uefi bios and asus EZ mode, a Fx 6300 processor and MSI r9 270x hawk edition graphics card. I decided to use the asus optimized/performance mode on the EZ setup screen. This changes the clock speeds of the bus, cpu, and ram, but not the video card. I have used the setting before with no problems, but this time the computer failed to start and the motherboard started the beep with the video card failure code. I cut all power to the computer then powered it up and it started normally. So I reset the bios settings and started to look for a reason it would do that. I opened the case and found that one of my fans on the graphics was not spinning. After a bit of testing, I found that the fan would start to spin if the card was under load or if I manually set the fan speed to 95% in afterburner. I'm pretty sure this is not a feature of the card nor the problem as temps hover around 65 - 70 c under load, but I'm not sure at this point. So I decided that it was probably a freak occurrence, but when I change the setting back to the performance mode I get the same beeping which was fixed by turning the power completely off and on same as before. Since this never happened before, I'm wondering if this is indicative of a bigger problem and if there is a fix?

I am unable update the driver, because windows then freezes just before the login screen when I update to the latest version. I've tried reseating the card, making sure the connections are all fine, blowing out dust including in the pci-e slot. I'm really unsure what is causing this.

Update: After doing some more research the I found out that the beep code is actually the one for memory. The problem did not fix itself after switching the memory around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a Memory test. You said the beep, was related to a memory problem. Do you have only one 8gb stick, or do you have splited over various sticks? If you have one stick and if it's been in use for a long time, it might be dying on you.

Had some weird behaviors with faulty sticks in past, like: drivers unloading and loading again for my graphics card, sound, etc. Once it didn't like the idea of booting up. Removed one of the sticks and problem solved. You should give it a go on Memtest, just to be sure if the stick is the problem.

Because if you did made a BIOS tune up, any change of voltage to sketchy mems might have broke them(you can log into windows, that led me up to that conclusion)

Cheers

Comment: it's a 2x4gb setup and it's not a tune up as much as it is a default setting in the bios. I tried the memtest on the motherboard which for this motherboard is a memory compatibility tuner as well and it seemed fix it entirely(or at least I cannot recreate the problem). I don't know why though as all the settings and clock speeds seem to be the same as before not sure about the voltage though.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds wiered. Try to change youre powersupply or graphiccard. It sounds to me like an hardwareproblem in the powersupply. Maybe u can check it by starting the pc using onboardgraphic?

Comment: unfortunately I do not have a spare power supply. Is there some other way to test? It's a corsair rm750x. As for onboard graphics I have an amd processor and amd hardward doesn't come with onboard graphics.

Comment: Why u vote my answer down? There are a lot of possibilities in youre scenario. Change components is a common way to find the problem...

Comment: I did not. It was a good suggestion but I currently do not have the rep to vote.